# How to select an inputs value in touch enabled browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, touch

**THE PROBLEM**

Safari is not conforming to standard textbox/input constraints.
Both maxlength and javascript select() do not output as expected.

```
<input type="text" value="12345" maxlength="5" onFocus="this.select();">
```

After some extensive testing I have discovered the following:

- Max length only fails when input **type is number**.
- Both **onFocus** and **onClick** fail to select the value on ipad with
  **Safari**.
- **OnClick** works with **Android** touch browser where **onFocus** does not.

**QUESTIONS**

When using safari on a touch device:

1. How to select an inputs value when focus is applied?
2. How to restrict the number of characters of an inputs value when type is number?

*(My test device is an ipad so the issue could be a touch input one, I have not tested this on a non touch safari browser.)*

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/p2vts/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MAX LENGTH**

Max length will restrict the number of characters permitted.

**Safari** does not support **maxlength** when using **type="number"**

---

**MAX**

When using **type="number"** it is recommended to use **min** and **max** to create a value range.

**Safari** does not support **min** and **max** values.

---

At the present time I recommend a combination of both max and maxlength for maximum compatibility:

```
<input class="Max" type="number" value="12345" maxlength="5" min="0" max="99999">
```

For **Safari** I would use a combination of **javascript** and **regex** to create input restrictions.

---

**JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY)**

```
$(".Max").keyup(function() {
    $(".Max").val(this.value.match(/^.{0,5}$/));
});
```

---

**REGEX**

`.`  Allows any character.

`\d` Replace with \d to allow only numbers.

`{0,5}` 0 is min length, 5 is max length.

Answer (score 0):

Select doesn't work onFocus, try using `onClick="this.select();"`

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2vts/1/

Comment: Thanks for your input. After testing, onFocus works better than onClick when using not touch devices as it allows selection of a value when focus is applied from a none click event such as tabbing of javascript. OnFocus fails when using touch browsers however using onClick DOES NOT select an inputs value when using touch in Safari.